# How to provide an RNN various type of inputs?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, neural-networks

I'm trying to build an RNN in Mathematica.
My window is only 2 but the variables are of different types:

```
{{"ch1" -> "525", "status" -> "P12", 
"Input" -> {0.005025125628140704`, 0.19`, 0.6869485330621257`, 
 9990.`, 1.`}}, {"ch1" -> "4432", "status" -> "K65", 
"Input" -> {0.01507537688442211`, 0.19375`, 0.7444255226482255`, 
 10045.`, 1.`}}} -> "Output" -> 0.
```

As you see, I labeled the variables, I know how to encode them, but I have no idea how to put them in an RNN model.
I know that if the input was all numeric I could have just set
"Input"->[2,3]
but what happens when one has other type of input variables?

Any help will most appreciated.

Comment: RNN ? Recurrent neural network? Answering your own question is a good way of documenting and sharing solutions you have found, but I would put more effort into making the question and answer more understandable for the average reader.

Answer (score 1):

To build an RNN model with multivariate variables to first deal with categorical variables as follows:

```
         enc = NetEncoder[{"Characters", {GetLevels[1], GetLevels[2], 
            GetLevels[3], GetLevels[4], pays, pays, pays, GetLevels[8], 
            GetLevels[9], GetLevels[10]}}]
```

Getlevels function just gets the levels (classes)

Than I combined the results of the encoding with my numerical variables

```
      Map[Flatten[List[enc[#[[1 ;; 10]]], #[[11 ;; 15]]]] &, dataTrain]
```

Finally, I partitioned the dataset into a window of size N (which can be chosen by you)

Note, I made sure to scale, or center my numerical variables.  I use "Characters" because my categorical variables levels change through time, so I cannot use "Class".  Furthermore, the levels are a concatenation of codes (which I don't know)